# How to open Calculator in Pop up window in Android?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am creating a pop up window for calculator on Button click. I have created and when run the application the app is crashes and I m getting `NullPointerException`. I want pop up calculator when i click on button.

Here is my Calculator Activity Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.damduppatyojna);
        
        imgCalculator = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.buttonCalculator);
        imgCalculator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
                View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_calculator, null);  
                final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                
                
                interestRatesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.interestSpinner);
                periodSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.periodSpinner);
                amountEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountEditText);
                toBeCalculatedTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toBeCalculatedTextView);
                
                //
                //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ir_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.interest_rate_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ir_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.interest_rate_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                ArrayAdapter<?> ir_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(DamDuppatYojna.this, R.array.interest_rate_array, R.id.interestSpinner);
                ir_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                interestRatesSpinner.setAdapter(ir_adapter);

                ir_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(DamDuppatYojna.this,R.array.period_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                ir_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                periodSpinner.setAdapter(ir_adapter);
              
                Button btnCalculator = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.calculatorButton);
                btnCalculator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.lokmanya.ResultActivity");
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putString("amount", amountEditText.getText().toString());
                        extras.putString("interestrate", interestRatesSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        extras.putString("period", periodSpinner.getSelectedItem()
                                .toString());
                        intent.putExtras(extras);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                    }
                });
                
                         
                Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
                btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  popupWindow.dismiss();
                     }});
                           
                         popupWindow.showAsDropDown(imgCalculator, 50, -30);
        
            }});
```

Here is Result Activity

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Now in On Create");
        this.setContentView(R.layout.result);
        
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),"Interest Rate: "+bundle.getString("interestrate"));
        
        float interestrate = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("interestrate"));
        float period = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("period"));
        float amount = Float.parseFloat(bundle.getString("amount"));
        
        float monthly = ((amount * (interestrate/100)*period)+amount)/(period * 12);
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.setData(Uri.parse("" + monthly));
        setResult(1,data); // first param to indicate resultCode
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Here is xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_Form"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amountTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/amountString" >
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/amountEditText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/interestRateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/interestRateString" >
            </TextView>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/interestSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Spinner>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loadPeriodTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/loanPeriodString" >
            </TextView>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/periodSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </Spinner>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/monthlyInstallmentTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/monthlyInstallmentString" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toBeCalculatedTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/toBeCalculatedString" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

  

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/calculatorButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save Settings" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dismiss"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Load Settings" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is Log cat text Information.

```
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.lokmanya.DamDuppatYojna$1.onClick(DamDuppatYojna.java:62)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-05 14:08:13.162: E/AndroidRuntime(751):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 14:08:15.503: I/Process(751): Sending signal. PID: 751 SIG: 9
```

Comment: the error is happening in `onClick` DamDuppatYojna.java:62

Comment: Please post DamDuppatYojna.java here

Comment: Also please indicate to us what is on line 62

Comment: THe line 62 in indicate =     interestRatesSpinner.setAdapter(ir_adapter);

Comment: @TJM Perhaps `R.array.interest_rate_array` does not exist?

Answer (score -1):

According to the code supplied, either `interestRatesSpinner` is null or `ir_adapter` is null. I doubt that interestRatesSpinner is null, though.

Comment: as the previous line was `ir_adapter.setDropDownViewResource` then I would assume that `ir_adapter` is not null.

Comment: Sorry it is a brutal world.  But if you change your answer, I will happy to remove the DV.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I cannot see how interestRatesSpinner would be null, though, seeing that it gets set at this line: `interestRatesSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.interestSpinner);`